# Form validations lost when included in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-directive

I have a directive, which successfully includes a template in my AngularJS app using Rails 4.2 and angular-rails-templates.

Everything seems to be working fine, even the two way data binding, although there is one exception. Form validation using AngularJS is lost if I include the `<form>` tag inside the template file.

When I run this in my local environment, Angular includes the template, display it on my main page. if you enter data the two way data binding updates, but the form validation is not handled by Angular, it uses HTML5 browser validation instead.

Any help appreciated, I assume there is some common thing I am missing, like how / when the template is inserted?

I have prepared [a working demo at Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9izYfTjdwnzWQ6sOicZ?p=preview), the same code executes without incident on Plnkr, but not when using Rails.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['templates']);

app.config([
  '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    return $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  }
]);

app.run(function() {
    return console.log('angular app running');
});

app.directive('serviceRequest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'service-request.html',
    controller:function() {
      this.request = {};
      this.addService = function(request) {
        //$http request
        this.request = {};
      }
    },
    controllerAs: 'service'
  };
});
```

The HTML template (service-request.html):

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate="">
<div>
  serviceForm is {{myForm.$valid}}
</div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Service Request</legend>
    <h1>{{service.request.number}} <small>{{service.request.reported | date}}</small></h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-10 small-centered">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="right">Number:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
            <label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="service.request.number" placeholder="small-9.columns" required/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-10 small-centered">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="right">Reported:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
              <input type="text" ng-model="service.request.reported" placeholder="small-9.columns" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid ">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't face with any validation problem in your demo. However 'templates' module dependency injection failed. Where is your 'templates' module?

Comment: Try this forked verison of your demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/03fsY3Mkrp6gFUd8Qq3c)

Comment: Hi Mehmut, the 'templates' module is a dependency of the angular-rails-templates gem, which allows me to use the rails asset pipeline with angular (https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates). I removed it from the demo code, so the demo runs, my issue essentially is validation doesn't work using this code in my rails application. It could possibly be a bug in angular-rails-templates.

Comment: Yuo may recompile by using  $compile service in link function... Maybe it solve you problem.